# Scheduling nodejs script as SQL Server Agent job

Tags: node.js, sql-server, powershell

Is there is a way to schedule a nodejs script to run through the SQL Server Agent job system? Currently I have a Powershell script that executes my .js file. Running the .ps1 file works fine manually and in Windows Task Scheduler. When I try to run the file through the agent, I get the following error:

> The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:  A job step received an error at line 1 in a PowerShell script. The corresponding line is 'Powershell -file "C:\Program Files\nodejs\scripts\script.ps1"'. Correct the script and reschedule the job. The error information returned by PowerShell is: 'node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet function script file or operable program.

The reason I want to add it to the SQL Server Agent is for consistency with other jobs I am running on the server. It would be ideal to have them all in a single place. If it isn't possible to get SQL to recognize the "node" command, then I can just use Task Scheduler.

Comment: Is the Node bin folder in the PATH environment variable for the account under which the SQL Agent service executes? Or alternatively, in the System's PATH environment variable? If not you'll need to specify the full path to the node executable when spawning your .js file.

Comment: That totally worked. I didn't even consider using the full path to the executable. Thanks!